# Windows 8 Metro apps in a corporate environment with BYODs

Tags: windows, windows-8

Ok, so I'm having issues finding an answer to this question. So far I've spent the better part of an hour on google, and talked to two MS reps (one at the conference I was just at, and my buddy who works for MS), but neither of them seemed to know; figured I'd see if any of you knew, so here goes:

Metro apps are currently being pushed as being available as only through the Windows App Store, which is all well and good for consumer apps as it guarantees quality. However in a corporate environment there are LOB apps that you may not want to make available to the public, the solution to this is to set up your own Corporate Hub on your domain and run your own internal app store. However this requires that the client computer be joined to the domain in order to get apps from this store, which is obviously something that is not going to happen with BYODs...

I read somewhere that it is possible to sideload apps if you have a special 'sideloading product activation key' (also, what is this sideloading application key? Is it a different windows key from the VL key, is it something on top of the normal windows activation key?) nowhere is it explained what this is, and no MS rep I've talked to has any idea about it either as it seems they have only been briefed on the consumer side of Metro development and deployment. However both of these options involve building a custom windows image with the app preinstalled and hence really don't help answer the question...

How do you install internal Metro style apps on an employee's personal BYOD machine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sideloading apps on Windows 8 Pro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008252/sideloading-apps-on-windows-8-pro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/04/25/deploying-metro-style-apps-to-businesses.aspx).

> Preparing other PCs
>
> Some business users might not use a PC that supports enterprise
>   sideloading. Common reasons for this are that the edition of Windows
>   that their enterprise uses doesn’t support this, or the IT admins do
>   not manage the PC. This scenario is becoming increasingly common with
>   the growing trend of personal devices used for work.
>
> To enable sideloading of a Metro style app onto a PC:
>
> Set Group Policy for “Allow all trusted apps to install”. If you
>   cannot use Group Policy, then you can set this through the following
>   setting:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Appx\AllowAllTrustedApps
>   = 1
>
> Verify that the app is signed by a CA that is trusted on the target machines Activate a special product key by using a script on
>   the target machine to enable sideloading. We'll go into more detail
>   about how the IT admin will acquire the product keys in an upcoming
>   blog post. The product key only needs to be install and activated once
>   on the PC.

Unfortunately they have yet to elaborate on the special key needed.