# Working around Windows Store App Sandbox

Tags: windows-8

I want to create a Metro app for learning and personal consumption purposes to do all sorts of low-level device API work, such as tracking power consumption, enumerating processes and calculating CPU usage per process, etc... Unfortunately, these Desktop APIs are forbidden from Metro applications.

My first attempt to work around this was to create a non-windows store C++ library, which has the `WINAPI_FAMILY` variable set correctly in order to use functions like `QueryIdleProcessorCycleTime()` and [`CallNtPowerInformation()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Unfortunately, it is this latter function call that fails when I pass it the [`ProcessorInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373184(v=vs.85).aspx) token in the first argument, with a `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` return code.

Interestingly, `CallNtPowerInformation()` works just fine when given `SystemBatteryState` as the first argument, so I imagine there is some kind of access privilege I am missing when running as a Metro app for getting processor info.  I read that Metro apps are run with [quite restricted privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040390/how-are-winrt-metro-apps-restrictions-enforced), and so I am looking for a way to increase these privileges to allow my API calls to go through properly.  To test that it is the process privileges and not a coding error, I used the C++ library from a console application, and everything worked just fine.

I would really like to not have to create a second, desktop background process that does all the dirty work and communicates the results to the Metro app over a socket.  I realize this can work, but I would rather have everything housed in the same process space.

Comment: Why bothering?, if it's for your personal use you can simply write a WPF application and you will get all the look of an Modern UI application without the hassle of jumping hoops around the limited permissions of WinRT, which is not intended for what you're doing anyway.

Comment: I want to be able to use it via a tablet-friendly interface. I like the Metro (or Modern UI) "look and feel", so if you can point me to a tutorial showing how to make a Modern UI-based App (Launchable from the Start Menu, opens in its own window, etc...) without living inside the Windows Store App sandbox, that would do splendidly.

Comment: Just code it in WPF with largish controls.  "Touch-friendly" is really a matter of design, not a matter of technology (at least as far as Windows is concerned).

Comment: Forgive me if I'm not understanding properly, but this would not give me the ability to do things like have a Live Tile, run on the touch-friendly start screen, etc.... right?  This would just basically be a large-sized desktop app with Metro-styled controls?

Comment: Correct.  With a WPF desktop application, you wouldn't be able to have a Live tile.  Your app could still be listed on the Start screen, but only with a static icon.  But for what you are trying to do, a desktop app is the way to go...it would be a pretty poor sandbox if there were ways to get around it.

Comment: For your idea of making a Windows Store/Metro app that communicates with a desktop process over sockets - note this Windows Store/Metro app wouldn't pass Windows Store certification (if that is something that is important to you), because of the dependency on the desktop app.  See certification requirement 3.1 at http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh694083: "Windows Store apps must not communicate with local desktop applications or services via local mechanisms, including via files and registry keys."