# How do I make a hybrid app in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-8, windows-runtime

How does Google Chrome make a hybrid app (i.e. one that works on the desktop and one that works out of the Modern UI, and that are switchable)? What new Windows API do they call?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12643029/1656796

Answer (score 2):

The only applications that can be "hybrid" are browsers.  See [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=243079) (link to Microsoft whitepaper on making a browser desktop and metro enabled).