# Create custom Windows 8 Start Tile for non Window 8 application

Tags: windows-8

After installing the Google Chrome Browser on my Win8 machine I was a bit supprised to see a customized tile on the Windows 8 Start menu. Unlike any other "standart" application Chrome has a dark gray tile with a little bit bigger icon.
Still it seems to be no Windows 8 application. If I start Chrome I will find myself back on the desktop and everything works like it did in the last few years.

How can I add this kind of customization to my own application?
I have a .NET 3.51 WPF application and so far I only have a normal tile with the default color and a small icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live tiles are only available to Windows Store apps.  They are not supported for normal desktop applications.  Google Chrome gets special behavior because it is the default browser, and the default browser can [act as a Windows Store app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12643228/1656796).