# Windows 8 Tile Icon for WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-8.1

guys, first time posting -

I'm a newbie to Windows development and VS (Using 2013 on Windows 8.1).

I've created a very simple application by the action of

File->New Project/WPF application.

The application works great, and does exactly what I'd like it to do.

I successfully added a large (128x128) icon and got it to look great on Windows 7's taskbar and start menu by right-clicking my project in the Solution Explorer and specifying my .ico file through there.

I also added the 'Icon' property to my MainWindow.xaml file and it even looks great on the taskbar of Windows 8...

However, it doesn't even display my app's icon on the Start Menu of Windows 8, and I am having a really hard time finding documentation specific to this issue.

I'm sure it's a no-brainer but I'm just stuck.

How do I get a nice icon and tile in Windows 8?

Answer (score 2):

Live tiles are only supported in Windows Store Applications but you can use some third-party solutions that provides a way to add this capability via the interoperation between your Desktop Application and separate Windows Store application (this one is installed on end-users computers and behaves like a server that can provide a Tile for its clients, which actually are the Desktop applications).
  For example, DevExpress solution - [WinRTLiveTileManager](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument15165).
Or you can implement this approach itself...

Answer (score 1):

Live tiles are only supported in Windows Store Apps unfortunately.

[See this thread...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469533/create-custom-windows-8-start-tile-for-non-window-8-application)

Comment: I understand this but surely there is a way to get my icon to display?