# Windows Store App Side Loading Product Key

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to deploy my Windows Store App in a system, which is not part of a domain.
As per the [MSDN document](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852635.aspx), we need to activate a side loading product key.

What exactly is this product key? 
From where I can get the Product Key?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sideloading apps on Windows 8 Pro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008252/sideloading-apps-on-windows-8-pro)

Answer (score 2):

You need to get key's through volume licensing.

check following article

[Deploying Metro style apps to businesses](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/04/25/deploying-metro-style-apps-to-businesses.aspx) out.

Also check this document

[Volume Licensing guide Windows 8 and Windows RT](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/4/3/9439A928-A0D1-44C2-A099-26A59AE0543B/Windows_8_Licensing_Guide.pdf)

[Microsoft are pricing Windows 8 Pro at $188 through Volume Licensing](http://www.windows8update.com/2012/10/07/microsoft-are-pricing-windows-8-pro-at-188-through-volume-licensing/)

Comment: Trying to get the point: The point in the Volume Licensing Guide is obviously that someone who own certain Volume Licensing products gets the right to sideload. This would not be suitable for companies that want to deliver apps to their customers who don't own Volume Licensing products. For those a company can "purchase Enterprise Sideloading licenses and MAK keys through Volume Licensing". But how that exactly works, particularly if I am a small company not wanting any Volume Licensing for myself, is still a mystery. Am I right?

Comment: Agree to Jurgen Bayer. As a developer if I want to distribute my application to my friends, who is using isolated systems, which are not part of any domain, why to go for a volume licensing?   Did it mean I couldn't able to run a Windows app without a domain & volume license?