# Client Machine requirements to run windows8-style app?

Tags: html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, system-requirements

I used Windows8 Release Preview and Visual Studio2012 RC to develop my windows8-style application, And I want to run my application on another machine(client).They have windows8 Release Preview on their machine . So here my question are:

1. Are they need to install any other software like Visual Studio2012
   and .NetFramework4.5 on their machine or not?
2. Can anyone give me some helpful information related to client's
   machine requirements to run metro app successfully?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> **Are they need to install any other software like Visual Studio2012 and .NetFramework4.5 on their machine or not?**

You can test it with `PowerShell`, it may require .net framework to install and for detailed information follow the links below.

Refer these:
[How to deploy a Metro App to the Desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451536/how-to-deploy-a-metro-app-to-the-desktop)
[Will Metro-style applications be able to be installed outside the market frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264451/will-metro-style-apps-be-able-to-be-installed-outside-the-market-frame)

[Deploying Metro style apps to non-development systems](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/7be92f16-7179-4d74-9915-c6f21e0f4c55)
[Sharing an app package locally (Metro style apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh975356) 
[Deploying Windows Metro style apps from Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh771031.aspx)

> **Can anyone give me some helpful information related to client's machine requirements to run metro app successfully?**

Check the Edit Section of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10265361/770710) and the reference video in the another answer for your second query.

[Supporting a Metro style Device App](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh454840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Hope this help you explore about the metro app deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure your machines to do remote debugging if you want. This is useful if your development machine is a traditional laptop or desktop but you want to debug your app running on a slate that has an accelerometer, GPS, multi touch, etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx has information on how to get that set up.